# is ORB+BFMatcher a good match for recognizing repetitive images (with slight variations?)

Tags: opencv, classification, matching, orb

I need to recognize images with hand-written numerals with known values. Physical objects with the number are always identical but come in slight variations of positions/scale/lighting. They are about 100 in number, having about 100x500 px in size.

In the first pass, the code should "learn" possible inputs, and then recognize them (classify them as being close to one of the "training" images) when they come again.

I was mostly following the [Feature Matching Python-OpenCV tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html)

Input images are analyzed first, keypoints & descriptors are remembered in the `orbTrained` list:

```
import cv2
import collections

ORBTrained=collections.namedtuple('ORBTrained',['kp','des','img'])
orbTrained=[]

for img in trainingImgs:
    z2=preprocessImg(img)
    orb=cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=400,patchSize=30,edgeThreshold=0)
    kp,des=orb.detectAndCompute(z2,None)
    orbTrained.append(ORBTrained(kp=kp,des=des,img=z2))
    z3=cv2.drawKeypoints(z2,kp,None,color=(0,255,0),flags=0)
```

A typical result of this first stage looks like this:

[image: example training image]

Then in the next loop, for each real input image, cycle through all training images to see which is matching the best:

```
ORBMatch=collections.namedtuple('ORBMatch',['dist','match','train'])
for img in inputImgs:
    z2=preprocessNum(img)
    orb=cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=400,patchSize=30,edgeThreshold=0)
    kp,des=orb.detectAndCompute(z2,None)
    bf=cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING,crossCheck=True)
    mm=[]
    for train in orbTrained:
        m=bf.match(des,train.des)
        dist=sum([m_.distance for m_ in m])
        mm.append(ORBMatch(dist=dist,match=m,train=train))
    # sort matching images based on score
    mm.sort(key=lambda m: m.dist)
    print([m.dist for m in mm[:5]])
    best=mm[0]
    best.match.sort(key=lambda x:x.distance) # sort matches in the best match
    z3=cv2.drawMatches(z2,kp,best.train.img,best.train.kp,best.match[:50],None,flags=2)
```

The result I get is nonsensical, and consistently so (only when I run with pixel-identical input, the result is correct):

[image: sample match]

What is the problem? Am I completely misunderstanding what to do, or do I just need to tune some parameters?

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure you're not reinventing the wheel by creating your own OCR library? There are many [free frameworks](https://medium.com/@balaajip/optical-character-recognition-99aba2dad314), some of which support training with custom character sets.

Second, you should understand what [feature matching is](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/df/d54/tutorial_py_features_meaning.html). It will find similar small areas, but isn't aware of other feature pairs. It will match similar corners of characters, not the characters itself. You might experiment with larger `patchSize` so that it covers at least half of the digit.

You can minimize false pairs by running feature detection only on a single digit at a time using thresholding and contours to find character bounds.

If the text isn't rotated, using roation-invariant feature descriptor such as ORB isn't the best option, try rotation-variant  descriptor, such as [FAST](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html#fast-feature-detector-in-opencv).

Comment: Thanks, I am not aiming an OCR at all, the initial labeling of *entire images* (as opposed to single digits) will be done by a human.

Comment: Tried with FAST (and BRISK for keypoint->feature) and the result is the same. Anyway, detecting single digits involves segmentation and other which I'd like to avoid. It is really simple "fuzzy" image matching which I need. Thanks for explaining about feature matching. New to the area :)

Answer (score 0):

According to authors of papers ([ORB](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6126544) and [ORB-SLAM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7219438)) ORB is invariant to rotation and scale "in a certain range". May be you should first match for small scale or rotation change.

Comment: The images are not rotated at all, the orientation does not change. They might be slightly misplaced or scaled vertically, but not rotated.